# How to divide percentage distribution of rows in two different tables in sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Hi i am using SQL Server 2012, i have a situation where have to divide table records in percent distribution let says i have 199 records in a table and i have to split this in two different tables 1 table having 43% of records and another table have remaining like 57% rows. Somebody please help me in these.

Comment: select top n percent

Comment: but can i how can i retrieve next 57% which does not include from 43% ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select top 43 percent from table order by field asc
select top 57 percent from table order by field desc
```

or

```
SELECT top 43 percent *
INTO newtable43 
FROM table

SELECT col1, col2, coln
INTO newtable57
FROM table
except
select col1, col2, coln from newTable43
```

Comment: its working for 100 records.But not working for records having 199 Rows in table getting 1 row common in both records.could you please help me to exclude that.